# How to convert multiple strings into the same char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I need a way to convert multiple strings into the same char array. For example if I have

```
string str1;
string str2;
char *myArray = new char[str1.size() + str2.size() + 1];
```

What's the best way to add the string characters into `myArray`?

Comment: `char myArray[str1.size() + str2.size() + 1]` is not ok, but look for `strcpy` and `strcat`

Comment: Edited using dynamic memory instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strcpy(myarray,(str1+str2).c_str())
```

or

```
strncpy(myarray,(str1+str2).c_str(),(str1+str2).length())
```

Comment: Though I would use strncpy.

Comment: It's safer to use `strncpy` though.

Answer (score 4):

You could use another `string` to combine the two:

```
auto myArray = str1 + str2;
```

You can then access the underlying (constant!) `char` array with the `.c_str` method or, if you want to modify certain characters, access them with the `operator[]` on `string`.

If you need an actual, modifiable `char*` style array, use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<char> myArray (str1.begin(), str1.end());
myArray.insert(myArray.end(), str2.begin(), str2.end());
myArray.push_back('\0');  // If the array should be zero terminated
```

You can then access the underlying, modifiable `char` array with the `.data` method.

Note that variable length arrays like `char myArray[str1.size() + str2.size() + 1]` are a compiler extension that only works on certain compilers. They are not standard C++.

Comment: I like this one.  It's idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

use strcpy and strcat:

```
strcpy(myArray,str1.c_str());
strcat(myArray,str2.c_str());
```

although , the expression `char myArray[str1.size() + str2.size() + 1]` will not compile under C++ , since VLAs are forbidden , use dynamic memory allocation:

```
char* myArray = new char[str1.size() + str2.size() + 1]
```

Comment: But you know that a char array isn´t a class?